# How can I compile the Mongodb-c-driver program?

Tags: c, linux, mongodb, linker

I use

```
gcc -o mongotest mongotest.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0)
```

for compilation mongodb c driver code, and then

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./mongotest
```

for run.

If I try without LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib I have

```
./mongotest: error while loading shared libraries: libmongoc-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I run program without LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib,
Is it correct to do so? How can I debug mongodb c driver programs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path `/usr/local/lib` should be in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or in one of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory. So the library `mongoc` will get into the cache when you issue command `ldconfig` as root.

You can check if library `mongoc` is in dynamic linker cache by executing this command

```
ldconfig -p | grep mongoc
```

If it is you are safe to run your program without explicitly specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Other way to check if your executable is correctly linked is by getting the linking information with `ldd` command. It will print all linked libraries.

```
ldd mongotest
```

If you can see `/usr/local/lib/libmongoc.so.[numbers]` that means it is linked with `mongoc` library.

Comment: I just want to give personal props to both retagging the question as appropriate and answering in the correct context. For other observers, the only tag on the question was just "mongodb".

Comment: @NeilLunn I had doubts if I should remove `mongodb` tag, if you're confident about it please do so.

Comment: I think the mongodb tag is still relevant as it pertains to c driver source. This is a programming forum right? I'm just glad you saw this as a largely "C" issue. And answered and tagged appropriately. So all perfectly valid. Good answer and handling.